# How to get the plugin.yml in a plugin jar?

Tags: java, server, minecraft, decompiler

I am currently coding a server-panel which will be able to configure plugins and so on.
The only problem I currently have is, I want to get the plugin.yml from inside the jar file.
Is there an API or anything out there, which can get this file decompiled and then read the plugin.yml????

Answer (score 0):

The plugin.yml gets put into the .jar. If you opened the .jar up with something like winrar you can access the file.

Comment: But I want to "open" it via a jar file to access the information inside this plugin.yml